# Can I shorten this method using Ramsey Uuid

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5, uuid

This is my current create method;

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    // 1. create a uuid string
    $uuid1 = Uuid::uuid1();
    $uuid = $uuid1->toString();

    // 2. check if it already exists in the database
    $response = Response::where('uuid', $uuid)->first();

    // 3. if it does, run this method again and get a new uuid
    if ($response) {
        return $this->create($request);
    }

    // 4. create an array with a uuid key and put the value in it
    $data['uuid'] = $uuid;

    // 5. create the record in the database
    $response = Response::create($data);

    // 6. look up the record I have just created to return in order to return the group
    $response = Response::where('uuid', $response->uuid)->first();

    // 7. redirect passing the uuid and the group
    return redirect()->route('survey', ['uuid' => $response->uuid, 'group' => $response->group]);
}
```

Parts of this seems a little excessive. Is there any way to safely get this down? Particularly, step 6. Is there no way to combine it with 5 and immediately reference the record I have created?

Also, is there a way I can remove steps 2 and 3 and be confident the Uuid's will never be duplicates? I know the chances are extremely small but still.

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to get same UUID, so you can safely remove steps 2 and 3. Although, if you want to check UUID in database you may use a `do-while-loop` instead steps 1, 2 and 3:

```
do {
    $uuid = (string) Uuid::uuid1();
} while ($response = Response::where('uuid', $uuid)->first());
```

Next, you do not have to run step 6. `Request::create` will return an Eloquent Request object so you can use it in step 7. The `$response->group` should be fetched by lazy load.